# RegEx for adding underscore before capitalized letters

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

How do I add underscore (_) before capitalized letters in a string, excepted the first one ?

```
[1] "VarLengthMean" "VarWidthMean"
```

I want it to become :

```
[1] "Var_Length_Mean" "Var_Width_Mean"
```

I considered using `str_replace_all` from `stringr`, but I can't figure out which regexp I should use.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to capture the lower case letter and the following upper case letter, and then insert the `_` while adding the backreference (`\\1`, `\\2`) of the captured group

```
sub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1_\\2", v1)
#[1] "Var_Length" "Var_Width"
```

---

If there are more instances, use `gsub`

```
gsub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", "_", v2,  perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Var_Length_Mean" "Var_Width_Mean"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("VarLength", "VarWidth" )
v2 <- c("VarLengthMean", "VarWidthMean")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
str_replace_all(v, "\\B([A-Z]+)", "_\\1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your language supports assertions, this is all you need

Find `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`
Replace `_`